# What Liquibase XML element to use to reset AUTO INCREMENT counter for a column in MySQL?

Tags: liquibase, auto-increment

In MySQL you would use this kind of SQL to reset the AUTO INCREMENT counter for a table:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 200;
```

What is the corresponding XML element to use in Liquibase?

I'm writing a `changeSet` that loads fresh data into an existing table, and I'd like the auto-increment primary key to start counting from `1` again. i.e.:

```
<changeSet id="reload-data" author="neek">
    <delete tableName="my_table"></delete>
    <!-- want to reset the auto_increment counter here -->
    <loadData tableName="my_table"
        file="data/fresh_data.csv" separator=","/>
    <rollback></rollback>
</changeSet>
```

This loads the data OK but the `id` column continues its value from the last known `id`, which is normal because I haven't reset the `AUTO_INCREMENT` for the table.

I can use a raw `sql` element, i.e.:

```
<sql>ALTER TABLE my_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1</sql>
```

But I worry the syntax would be different for other databases and best handled by a specific Liquibase command.

Perhaps we could use `addAutoIncrement` https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/add-auto-increment.html on the column, which already *is* auto increment, to reset it?  Seems a bit heavy handed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no Liquibase change for resetting autoIncrement.

As you mentioned, you can always use `<sql>` change.

If you have to use Liquibase changes (assuming you don't have any foreign keys related to that column, since you want to reset autoIncrement), as a not very good workaround you may try dropping the autoIncremented column, and then recreating it.

```
<!-- drop primary key -->
<changeSet id="foo1" author="bar">
    <dropColumn tableName="table_name" columnName="auto_incremented_column"/>
</changeSet>

<!-- recreate autoIncremented column -->
<changeSet id="foo2" author="bar">
    <addColumn tableName="table_name">
        <column name="auto_incremented_column" autoIncrement="true" type="bigserial">
            <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```